# Is my platy pregnant?

Tags: aquarium, fish, pregnancy

[image: the predominantly orange pltay in the picture)]

I think my platy is pregnant (the predominantly orange pltay in the picture). I bought her a few days ago and have noticed her to be getting larger each day but I'm looking for more advice.

Comment: the orange one is very unlikely to be pregnant males rarely do,https://fishkeepingguide.net/platy-fish/identify-male-and-female-platy-fish/

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Because an answer to a very similar quedtion exists, yours will probably be closed. Please have a look into this linked similar question to answer yours :)

Comment: @trondhansen despite how it looks on the picture she is definitely female, it is the poor quality of the picture which distorts the fins.

Comment: @Allerleirauh thankyou I have looked at the link you have suggested and it does look as though my thoughts were correct as she is displaying the mentioned behaviours.

Comment: after  looking at the fullscreen picture i am 100% sure that the orange platy is a male and the smallest of your platy is a female.we have a lot of Q&As about platy`s please take a look in the different related posts and please follow the links in the posts too as there is a lot of information to be found.